# Query in C Pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to print a pointer of char type in c , i'm able to see the values and it's memory address as below

```
     char *ptr = "I am a string"; 

     printf("\n  value [%s]\n",ptr);
     printf("\n  address [%d]\n",&ptr);
```

But when i print directly the pointer as below, it's showing error as `Segmentation fault`

```
     char *ptr = "I am a string"; 

     printf("\n  value [%s]\n",*ptr);
```

Please tell me what's going wrong here

Note: if i change the format in printf to [%d] or [%i] it's printing.

Comment: `printf("\n  value [%s]\n",ptr);`

Comment: @Sukumar Do you know what `*ptr` is? What is the value and the type of `*ptr`?

Comment: @Als I don't think quoting Sukumar's second line of code will help in understanding what the issue is.

Comment: @MrLister: I would advice to read properly before commenting. And I posted it as an comment because I didn't have enough time or motivation to explain the answer in detail.Feel free to add your own answer instead of criticizing others.

Comment: @Als what you posted is exactly the same as what Sukumar wrote in his question. So what does it help?

Comment: @MrLister Gah! You're right. Comment withdrawn.

Comment: the correct format specifier for a pointer is %p, not %d, therefore better is `printf("\n  address [%p]\n",ptr);`

Comment: @user411313 you are right. now it's printing after changing to [%p]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a 0-terminated `char` array. If the corresponding argument to `printf` is `*ptr`, a `char`, that is a) undefined behaviour and b) probably leads to the value of the character (promoted to an `int`) and possibly some arbitrary adjacent bytes, being interpreted as a pointer. Following that presumed pointer is likely to access memory not allocated to your program.

Answer (score 4):

`*ptr` is a char, not a char pointer, and `%s` expects a char pointer (to a C-string). When treating the char as a pointer, `printf` tries to access an invalid memory address, and you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yeap... trying to access memory on 0x00 - 0xff :)

Comment: @MrJames address 0x0049 to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in the format `"%s"` into `printf`, the function expects a pointer to an array of `char`s.